# async await function - await not waiting for the first function

Tags: node.js, async-await

Hey im trying to refresh the page only after a function that loop over csv file and make a get request bassed on the csv parameters .

in reallity the page refreshing ammitiatly before the loop function is fully done.
what am i missing here?

```
 .on('end',function(){

const refresh = function(){
  res.redirect(req.get('referer')); 
}

async function firstFunction(){
 loopCsv();
}

async function secondFunction(){
  await firstFunction();
  refresh();
};

secondFunction();
```

});

Comment: `firstFunction` doesn't wait for `loopCsv` to finish. It's just a fire and forget, so `await firstFunction()` will similarly not wait for `loopCsv`

Comment: so what is your sudgestion?

Answer (score 1):

if all your code is correct, because i cant see your function loopCsv ..., if all is ok and loopCsv is async function you can put the code below at firstFunction

```
return await loopCsv();
```

Comment: still not working ..

Comment: @Timmy pleace edit your post and copy all your code source

Comment: Hey @Omar I edited the code .. you can see the loopcsv function

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the `loopCsv` method inside the `firstFunction`. other wise the `async` decleration on that function is useless (`async` signature just allows you to use `await` inside of it)

```
 .on('end',function(){

const refresh = function(){
  res.redirect(req.get('referer')); 
}

async function firstFunction(){
 await loopCsv();
}

async function secondFunction(){
  await firstFunction();
  refresh();
};

secondFunction();
```